# Is there a way to allow Docker Container to connect to host but not to internet

Tags: docker

I want to connect my container to host but not to internet i.e It should be a able to connect to a non container process on host eg:  `localhost:5000`

but not to internet

Comment: Read the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Comment: please answer the question i have searched many site but didn't found anything useful

Comment: #1 Do you need to consume one service which is outside your container? #2 Do you need to protect your container process , I mean that, no one must be able consume your service or do you need to ensure that your container process does not consume nothing from internet?

Comment: I want my container process not to consume anything from internet

Answer (score 0):

If you are executing calls from **inside** a container and you want to address your **host**, then you cannot use the `localhost` address (because that would still point to the inside of the container).

So, what you need to do, is use the `0.0.0.0` address (`0.0.0.0:5000` in your case).